# How to bind a call method to a new button in x-editable?

Tags: jquery, x-editable

I added a new button to the X-Editable template:

```
$.fn.editableform.buttons =
  '<button type="submit" class="editable-submit">save</button>' +
 '<button type="button" class="editable-cancel">cancel</button>' +
 '<button type="button" class="editable-test">test</button>';
```

How do I bind a click method to this button and get data from the editable instance? Here's my failed attempt:

```
$("button.editable-test").on("click", function() { console.log($(this).data('editable')); }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("button.editable-test").on("click", function()
```

should be

```
$(document).on("click", "button.editable-test", function()
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/

You will notice in the documentation that you have to pass `'action', 'item', function` to the .on method and the `$('item').on` should always be an `item` higher up the dom (document or body should always work but for efficiency try and pick a closer item such as the `"button.editable-test"` container).

Comment: Thanks, this solves the call binding to the button part. Still need to figure out how to get the editable instance inside the function.